# How to use mutate within a for loop after using a group_by?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Sample dataframe is as follows:

```
dat = data.frame(a = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,4),rep(3,7)), b = c(1:16)) 

for (i in 1:21){
dat %<>% group_by(a) %>% 
  mutate(paste('lag_',i,,sep = '') = lag(b, n = i))
}
```

However, the error popped up:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  dat%<>% group_by(a) %>% 
    mutate(paste('lag_',i,,sep = '') ="
```

Is there any way to name the variable by using mutate after group_by within forloop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat = data.frame(a = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,4),rep(3,7)), b = c(1:16)) 

for (i in 1:21){
  dat %<>% group_by(a) %>% 
    mutate(!!paste('lag_',i,sep = '') := lag(b, n = i))
}
dat
#> # A tibble: 16 × 23
#> # Groups:   a [3]
#>        a     b lag_1 lag_2 lag_3 lag_4 lag_5 lag_6 lag_7 lag_8 lag_9 lag_10
#>    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#>  1     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#>  2     1     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#>  3     1     3     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#>  4     1     4     3     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#>  5     1     5     4     3     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#>  6     2     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#>  7     2     7     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#>  8     2     8     7     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#>  9     2     9     8     7     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 10     3    10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 11     3    11    10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 12     3    12    11    10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 13     3    13    12    11    10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 14     3    14    13    12    11    10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 15     3    15    14    13    12    11    10    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 16     3    16    15    14    13    12    11    10    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> # ℹ 11 more variables: lag_11 <int>, lag_12 <int>, lag_13 <int>, lag_14 <int>,
#> #   lag_15 <int>, lag_16 <int>, lag_17 <int>, lag_18 <int>, lag_19 <int>,
#> #   lag_20 <int>, lag_21 <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

For more details, see https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html?q=:=#tidy-dots